# Inserting multiple Strings into a JTextPane with a TitledBorder in a single Thread locks cause programm to lock up

Tags: java, swing, thread-safety, jtextpane, event-dispatch-thread

I have encountered a **very** strange problem when trying to insert multiple Strings into a JTextPane that has a TitledBorder (this is important, the problem seems to only occur with TitledBorder specifically, other Borders or no Border at all work fine) from a Thread. The (for this problem) significant part of my test code looks like this:

```java
JTextPane myTextPane = new JTextPane();
myTextPane.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Some title"));
StyledDocument doc = myTextPane.getStyledDocument();
SimpleAttributeSet sas = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setForeground(sas, Color.BLACK);

private void insertTwoStrings()
{
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            docTest.insertString(docTest.getLength(), "first string ", sas);
            docTest.insertString(docTest.getLength(), "second string\n", sas);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Now to the problem: the insertTwoStrings() method works fine **sometimes**, but other times it fails **very badly** in a way that locks up the entire application (i have to kill the process to shut the application down). So i opened the program in the debugger and replicated the problem there, when the problematic Thread got locked up i suspended it and took a closer look at the program counter position:

[image: Current position of program counter]

It seems like this synchronized(this) is the cause of my problem. Is this actually a bug or am i making some kind of mistake?

In case someone wants to replicate this, for the problem to occur you have to meet all of the following three criteria:

1. inserting text into a JTextPane (i.e. into its StyledDocument) **from a Thread**
2. invoking StyledDocument.insertString(...) **multiple times** within the thread, not just once
3. the JTextPane must have a TitledBorder

Executing the Thread will still work *sometimes*, but every now and then it will fail and lock up the entire program.

Comment: Swing components are not thread safe and should only be accessed on the Event Dispatch Thread. So your code snippet violates the swing threading rules.

Comment: Thanks! I am not very experienced when it comes to Swing, could you maybe point me to the right direction regarding how i would do that?

Comment: - (correct me maybe I'm wrong) but I'm see similair question on another Java forum

Comment: See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others already point out Swing is not threadsafe unless the specific method is documented to be threadsafe. Swing provides several Utility methods and classes that can pass messages to the event dispatch thread - SwingUtilities contains invokeLater and invokeAndWait, the SwingWorker threads can send "finished" work to a callback.

```
// run will be executed on the EDT
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        docTest.insertString(docTest.getLength(), "first string ", sas);
        docTest.insertString(docTest.getLength(), "second string\n", sas);
    }
});
```

The above code will execute run on swings event dispatch thread, so take care to keep run() short (read fast) or your User interface will slow to a crawl.

Answer (score 2):

- even `Runnable#Thread` is proper of ways, but common issue that never notified EDT

meaning anything with `Document`, model for [JTextComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)

```
docTest.insertString(docTest.getLength(), "first string ", sas);
docTest.insertString(docTest.getLength(), "second string\n", sas);
```

- you have issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and this issue is/will/could be the same for `"ThreadSafe"` methods (`setText("")` for example) implemented in Swing API by using plain `Thread` or `Runnable#Thread`
- have to wrapp `docTest...` into `invokeLater()`
- no idea why is there `synchonized`, then could be better to use `invokeAndWait()`,
- notice `invokeAndWait(`) must be caled out of EDT, tested if `isEventDispatchThread` before, otherwise caused (a few ecxeptions) locking current GUI, and couldn't be reusable and current JVM must be closed in some cases
- you can to use `SwingWorker`, there are methods motified EDT quite properly, e.g. `publish()`, `process()` and `done()`